# LINQ - get parent based on last child condition

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have the current entities:

**Students (Id, Name,..)**

**Grades (Id, Student_Id, Grade)**

A student can have more of no grades..

Using LINQ (Entity Framework) how can I get a list of all students that have the last grade different than 10!

I was trying:

```
var students = db.students.Where(c => c.Grades.LastOrDefault().Grade != 10) .ToList();
```

The problem is since I may not have any grades, the `LastOrDefault` can be `null`.

Comment: `The problem is since I may not have any grades, the LastOrDefault can be null.`  That would matter if this was LINQ to objects, but with EF this is getting translated into SQL, and SQL propogates nulls, rather than throwing NRE.

Comment: Do students with no grades get counted? Like, does "no grades" mean count as a "last" grade != 10 or not?  Also, you need to be clear about what "last grade" means - if it is the most recent based on some date, or the highest id, or something like that, you MUST make sure to use `OrderBy` to ensure that `LastOrDefault` gets the correct record!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nobody seems to notice that `Last(Ordefault)` is not supported in LINQ to Entities. So you have to use another approach:

```
var students = db.students
                 .Where(c => c.Grades.OrderByDescending(g => g.Date)
                 .FirstOrDefault().Grade != 10).ToList();
```

I have to guess that there is some useful property by which you can order the Grades (a `Date`?). You don't want to depend on the order the database happens to produce them.

As said in a comment, null values don't throw exceptions in SQL, the language in which this expression is evaluated.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply check for existence of `Grades` before calling `Last()` as in

```
var students = db.students
    .Where(c => c.Grades.Count() > 0 && c.Last().Grade != 10)
    .ToList()
```

Or as pointed out in the comment, you can take advantage of the `Any()` function

```
var students = db.students
    .Where(c => c.Grades.Any() && c.Last().Grade != 10)
    .ToList()
```

Comment: `Where(c => c.Grades.Any() && c.Last().Grade != 10)` Take advantage of  `Any()` function

Answer (score 1):

If you are using C# 6 (.NET 4.6 or higher), you can use the new Elvis Operator .? together with the Null coalesing operator.

```
var students = db.students.Where(c => c.Grades.LastOrDefault()?.Grade != 10 ?? false).ToList();
```

Basically the elvis operator will return null, if LastOrDefault() is null, else it will return the value of Grade

Two other possible ways:
Check if c.Grades has any values or to check if LastOrDefault() returns null.
Way 1:

```
var students = db.students.Where(c => c.Grades.LastOrDefault() == null ? false : c.Grades.LastOrDefault().Grade != 10).ToList();
```

Way 2:

```
var students = db.students.Where(c => c.Grades.Any() && c.Grades.LastOrDefault().Grade != 10).ToList();
```

In all 3 ways the result for students is a list where every student has at least 1 grade where the last one is not 10.